# Replace text using input box with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create 2 input box to replace text with javascript?

Instead of editing code every time to replace different text
what I want is a small UI with Input box A and Input box B and a button

The first input box will contain text to replace(box A) and second one with what to replace (box B) and onClick the text will be replaced.

For example replacing apple from this text  "This is a red apple."

```
.replace (/apple/, "grape")

.replace (/contents of box a/, "contents of box b") ///what I want to do
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Can you share your html and script code what you tried so far?

Comment: So you add two textboxes and reference the values....

Comment: @epascarello  yes, that what I want to do. did not know what to search , now I do thanks

Comment: So do it........

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">This is apple. This is contents of box a.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
str = str.replace("apple", "grape");
str = str.replace("contents of box a", "contents of box b");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its not what I want but UI to put text to replace

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood (maybe try to add more details to the question), but this might give you a clue or two

```
var input_a = document.querySelector('#input_a');
var input_b = document.querySelector('#input_b');

input_a.addEventListener('change', do_replace );
input_a.addEventListener('keyup', do_replace );

function do_replace() {
   var value_a = input_a.value;
   var replaced_a = value_a.replace('wat you dont want', 'what you want');
   var input_b = replaced_a;
}
```